# LSTM: training and backpropagation for multistep prediction

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am training an LSTM for time series prediction. I do not only need to predict the next timestep but a series of timesteps ahead. That is, from a set of input `1, 2, 3, 4` I need to predict `5, 6, 7, 8, 9`. My dataset is in the following format:

```
input             label
1, 2, 3, 4        5
2, 3, 4, 5        6
```

To train it, I define a window size `n` that determines the input size and a window size `m` that determines how many steps in the future I want to predict. So, this is what I do for one single batch:

```
for _ in range(m):

    set hidden_state = 0

    input             prediction      label      loss
    1, 2, 3, 4   ->   8               5          mse(label, prediction)
    2, 3, 4, 8   ->   11              6          mse(label, prediction)
    3, 4, 8, 11  ->   2               7          mse(label, prediction)
    ...
    ...

loss = mse(total_loss)
loss.backward()
```

[the way I define the input each time is very important] 
For every prediction, I calculate the loss and that the prediction as a last value of the next input. The loss is added to a total_loss buffer and gets averaged at the end. After `m` iterations, I backpropagate the total_loss (gradients are stored for every prediction and hidden_state) and re-start with a new batch, setting the hidden_state = 0. 
The rationale behind this choice is that the loss encodes how well the algorithm predicts the whole series and not just the next timestep (as it does if I always calculate the loss for `1,2,3,4 -> 5`). I am not very sure that this is the right approach since the input is mainly composed of predictions after the first step. 
Is this a common way to train time series? Are there any specific problems with this method?